# Why can't Index Only Scan be used on index created with COALESCE?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, internals

PostgreSQL 9.4
The table is created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id integer,
    date date,
    value numeric(14,3)
);
```

I'm optimizing a query using the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function and `COALESCE`. For the most efficient, I tend to use `Index Only Scan` in the following query:

```
SELECT id, c_val
FROM (
    SELECT id, COALESCE(value, 0) c_val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC NULLS LAST) rn
    FROM foo) sbt
WHERE sbt.rn = 1;
```

So, if I create the index as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX ON foo (id, date DESC NULLS LAST, value);
```

the planner choose to use `Index Only Scan`, but if I do it in this way:

```
CREATE INDEX ON foo (id, date DESC NULLS LAST, COALESCE(value, 0));
```

the planner will do just `Index Scan`.

Why? I'm trying to avoid the cost of evaluating the `COALESCE` function while executing the query. Why isn't it work with `Index Only Scan`?

Comment: The "cost" of `coalesce()` is nearly zero, don't worry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you wrongly assumed that `COALESCE(value, 0)` in your `SELECT` matters in terms of an index usage. To tell the truth it's only view transformation done **after** the rows values are returned.

What matters as far as an index usage is concerned is your `WINDOW FUNCTION`. Firstly you partition by `id` and seccondly you order values in each partition by `date DESC NULLS LAST`. This two things determine that index like `CREATE INDEX ON foo (id, date DESC NULLS LAST, ...)` is useful whatever you put in next positions. *Notice that if you change order of `id` and `date` at index creation, PostgreSQL will not use the index at all.*

Now, you must know that `INDEX ONLY SCAN` could be use only if the index itself stores the whole untouched row values requested by query. After [PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/index-scanning.html):

> If the index stores the original indexed data values (and not some lossy representation of them), it is useful to support index-only scans, in which the index returns the actual data...

In your case your seccond index stores *some lossy representation* of a row because value of last column is transformed by a function and query asked for `id`, `value` and `date`. PostgreSQL isn't so smart to see that it's only substiturion of `NULLs` by `0`. For him it's not the original value. So we need to access table to get the original row values (in the end using plain `INDEX SCAN`). After that values are formatted for output and `COALESCE(values, 0)` happens.

**Edit:**

I think that explanation is sufficient to you as far as your question about internals is concerned. To talk about `COALECE()` evaluation cost, I agree with [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) that you probably shouldn't worry about that.

Comment: Ah, I dind't know that fetching happens first in the case of `COALESCE`, if I can say so...

Comment: Since I answered you question accurately and explained things, and you learn something you didn't know (as you said it) why not accept my answer?